# Sparrow always set itself as the default mail reader

Tags: mail.app, sparrow

I have Sparrow configured for my personal gmail account, and Mail.app for working.  However, every time I open Sparrow, it will set itself as the default .eml file reader, although I didn't config the Sparrow doing so (as in the following picture).  I like to use the Mail.app as the default .eml file reader, so every time after I use Sparrow, I have manually re-config the .eml file reader to Mail.app.

Is it a Sparrow's bug?

[image]

Comment: I've pinged the developpers, they're looking into it. Hopefully, they'll update here with the result. Otherwise, I'll keep an eye on the changelog.

Comment: I upgraded to the latest version, v1.4, and found that the mentioned bug seems fixed.

Comment: Since this is just a bug (that will/has already been) fixed, I'm closing this as too localized. It won't be useful to someone in the future.